# Why are my UDP packets not being received when sent to my own public IP?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp

I have a simple C# UDP server which is running a listener and a sender on separate threads. The listener binds to the current machine on a specified port and listens for any incoming UDP packets. The writer will send data to a given endpoint, which works in some cases.

The problem I'm having at the moment though is that when UDP packets are sent to my public IP on the listening port, they are not being received, however if I change the public IP to my router ip (192.168.0.2) then it works fine. This isn't what I'm looking for as the hosted server can only send to the client's public IP.

**Process**

Sender ("5.5.5.5", 1000) sends data via UDP to a given endpoint ("1.2.3.4", 1000)

Server on ("1.2.3.4", 1000) receives data

Echoes data back to sender using their public IP and listening port ("5.5.5.5", 1000)

Why is the data not being sent back to the public ip even though it is listening on the given port?

---

When testing locally, running the server and client on the same machine, when the endpoint is set to my public IP and listening port, the data isn't received locally at all.

```
  Program()
    {

        ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1000);
        listenSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        listenSocket.Bind(ipep);//this should bind to port 1000


        Thread listenThread = new Thread(listen);
        Thread writeThread = new Thread(send);

        listenThread.Start();
        writeThread.Start();

        listenThread.Join();
        writeThread.Join();

    }

    void listen()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting listener for echoback...");
        while (true)
        {
            IPEndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
            EndPoint epSender = (EndPoint)sender;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            listenSocket.ReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epSender);

            string receivedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("Received via UDP: " + receivedString);
        }

    }

    void send()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test message".ToCharArray());
//when this is router IP 192.168.0.2, it works fine, but not for public ip
            UdpClient client = new UdpClient("PUBLIC IP", 1000);
            client.Send(msg, msg.Length);

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

        }

    }
}
```

---

I have noticed that when the UDP packet is received by the 'server', the sender port is always different and I read that you need to reply on this IP/port, but the client is not listening on the receiving port so I create a new endpoint with the sender's address, and the port it should be listening on. So how do games or other applications manage this where there is constant communication from client-server via UDP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the world of NAT traversal.  Where IP addresses get translated and port numbers aren't mapped consistently.

What you are attempting is called [NAT Hairpinning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning).  Whereby a client node behind your NAT attempts to send to its own public IP address.  **Not all NATs support this mode.**.  This is why sending to your private IP address works,   but not your public IP address.  When your NAT receives the datagram with the IP address destined to its own public IP, it does not know which of the many nodes its managing to send it back to (your pc, your phone, your game console, etc...). So it just drops the packet.

Comment: Oh I see, well this was just for testing on my own machine. The real set up produces a similar scenario where my client is hosted on my pc, and the server is hosted on AWS. The server can successfully receive the udp, but when it tries to echo back to my public IP (where the packet came from), it isn't received. Is this a similar issue and if so how do games manage to work around it?

Comment: Yeah but surely there is a way without port forwarding? Imagine a multiplayer game for example, you don't need to do any port forwarding (unless they do it for you in the background somehow), but most games UDP to communicate.

Comment: In a general client-server scenario, as long as the server is echoing back to the ip and port it receives the client's packet on and using the same socket to send back on.  Then it should work.

Comment: @selbie Ahh that's what I'm not doing at the moment, however I'm pretty sure I tried that and it still didn't work. I will double check.

Comment: By sending an outbound UDP packet through your NAT to the public server, the NAT creates a port mapping and quite possibly changes both the IP and port.  As long as your server sends back to the address (and port) it sees the packet come from (**and not a hard coded port number**), and with the same socket (same local server port) it should work.

Comment: @selbie thanks a lot that was it! I had two sockets instead of a single one for sending and receiving but that explained why it wasn't being received.